# Average Voltage of a 3phase full wave bridge diode rectifier derivation

Tags: power-electronics, bridge-rectifier, full-bridge

Why three phase bridge rectified waveform is integrated over the half period \$\pi/6\$\ to find the average voltage? Should it not be integrated over \$\pi/3\$\, as the wave form repeat itself after \$\pi/3\$\ which is the time period of this waveform. Below is the waveform and related derivation. The book is Power Electronics 3rd Edition by Muhammad H. Rashid, page no 93.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waveform from \$\pi /6\$ to \$\pi /3\$ is just the symmetrical reflection of the waveform from \$0\$ to \$\pi /6\$. Therefore, the average value will be the same over those two periods.

Comment: I am asking about integrating over two periods from 0 to \$\pi/3\$\ and from 0 to \$\pi/6\$\

Comment: Yes, but the result will be the same because the waveforms during the second half of the \$\pi /3\$ period are just a reflection of the waveforms in the first half of the same period.